# Get non zero values for each column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas dataframe as `df`:

```
accel access adviser afpif  afp   publish  afraid verizon
0.00  0.14    0.00   0.00   0.00   0.13    0.00   0.44
0.13  0.00    0.00   0.77   0.00   0.00    0.22   0.00
0.00  0.00    0.87   0.00   0.34   0.00    0.00   0.00
......................................................
.....................................................
```

I also have a list `L` which consist columns names as elements

```
L=['accel','afp','publish']
```

All I want to extract non zero values of these list elements based on `pandas dataframe`.

Expected Output:-

```
dictionary={'accel':0.13,'afp':0.34,'publish':0.13}
```

Comment: all your columns have only one non-zero value? if not what your expected output will be?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar yes they have only one non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with dict comprehension and [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) if always exist at least one non 0 value:

```
d = {c: df.loc[df[c] ! =0, c].iat[0] for c in L }
print (d)
{'accel': 0.13, 'afp': 0.34, 'publish': 0.13}
```

More general working with only `0` columns too:

```
d = {c: next(iter(df.loc[df[c] != 0, c]), 'no value') for c in L }
print (d)
{'accel': 0.13, 'afp': 0.34, 'publish': 0.13}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jpp, not using chained indexing and using `.loc` instead -

```
op = { col: df.loc[df[col].ne(0), col].tolist() for col in L }
```

Output -

```
{'accel': [0.13], 'afp': [0.34], 'publish': [0.13]}
```

This implementation will be more robust in the sense it can retrieve multiple non-zero values. However, if you are sure you just want the one value, you can filter it out inside the `dict` comprehension itself -

```
op = { col: df.loc[df[col].ne(0), col].iat[0] for col in L }
```

OR

```
op = { col: df.loc[df[col].ne(0), col].values[0] for col in L }
```

Output -

```
{'accel': 0.13, 'afp': 0.34, 'publish': 0.13}
```

Note: If you are sure your non-zero values are positive, you can use `>0` or the [`Series.gt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) API

Comment: Chained indexing is explicitly discouraged in the docs. Use `.loc` instead.

Comment: Thanks @jpp! Updated ans

Comment: Also don't convert to list. Use `iloc` or `iat` or `values[0]` instead. There's no reason for list conversion to extract the first value!

Comment: @jezrael Probably not a bad click he had more things on his mind. I think I ended up learning more while answering a Q rather than asking. Thanks a bunch !

Answer (score -3):

One line answer would be:

```
df.sum().to_dict()
```