# Find columns with only one non-zero value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let me begin by noting that this question is very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054945/get-non-zero-values-for-each-column-in-pandas) about getting non-zero values for each column in a pandas dataframe, but in addition to getting the values, I would also like to know the row from which it was drawn. (And, ultimately, I would like to be able to re-use the code to find columns in which a non-zero value occurred some x amount of times.)

What I have is a dataframe with a count of words for a given year of documents:

```
|Year / Term | word1 | word2 | word3 | ... | wordn |
|------------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-------|
| 2001       |  23   |   0   |   0   |     |   0   |
| 2002       |   0   |   0   |  12   |     |   0   |
| 2003       |   0   |  42   |  34   |     |   0   |
| year(n)    |   0   |   0   |   0   |     |  45   |
```

So for `word1` I would like to get both 23 and 2001 -- this could be as a tuple or as a dictionary. (It doesn't matter so long as I can work through the data.) And ultimately, I would like very much to be able to discover that `word3` enjoyed a two-year span of usage.

FTR, the dataframe has only 16 rows but it has a lot, a lot of columns. If there's an answer to this questions already available, revealing the weakness of my search fu, I will take the scorn as my just due.

Answer (score 2):

In you case `melt` then `groupby`

```
df.melt('Year / Term').loc[lambda x : x['value']!=0].groupby('variable')['value'].apply(tupl)
```

Comment: I have not come across `melt` before. I will try it and check this as answered if this works, and thank you!